# Whats wrong with this basic shell program? it will run fine for the first few commands but results always ends in a seg fault

Tags: c, linux, shell, lex

I have to build a simple shell program using lex and c code. The lex portion is for breaking down the input. It has been provided for me and I'm not expected to change it. I'm in the process of getting my code to run basic commands like "ls". It seems to work the first few times I run the command but eventually always seg faults. Here is the lex code provided:

```
%{
int _numargs = 10;
char *_args[10];
int _argcount = 0;
%}

WORD [a-zA-Z0-9\/\.-]+
SPECIAL [()><|&;*]

%%
_argcount=0; 
_args[0]=NULL; 

{WORD}|{SPECIAL} { 
if(_argcount < _numargs-1) {
_args[_argcount++]= (char *)strdup(yytext);
_args[_argcount]= NULL;
}
}

\n return (int)_args;

[ \t]+

.

%%

char **getln() {
return (char **)yylex();
}
```

This is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

extern char **getln();

int main() {
    int i;
    char **args; 
    int child1;
    int status1;
    int counter=0;
    int argCount = 1;

    char **array = (char **)malloc(1500 * sizeof(char *));
    for (i = 0; i < 1500; ++i) {
        array[i] = (char *)malloc(500);
    }
    strcpy(array[0],"ls\0");
    array[1] = NULL;

    while(1) {
        args = getln();
        printf("is error here?");
        strcpy(array[0], args[counter]);

        for(i = (counter+1); args[i] != NULL; i++) {
            printf("\nRight before copying to subarray");
            strcpy(array[argCount], args[i]);
            argCount++;
        }

        array[argCount] = NULL;

        if (strcmp(args[counter],"exit")==0) exit(0);

        child1 = fork();
        if(child1==0){

            execvp(array[0], array);
            printf("Unknown command, please try again.");
            exit(1);
        }
        else{
            while (wait(&status1) != child1);
        }

        for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++) {
            printf("Argument %d: %s\n argCount: %d", i, args[i], argCount);
        }
        argCount = 1;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice. If there is some simple way to adjust the getln() function to overwrite the args array each time it is called that might be easier than what I am attempting but I have no idea how to go about that.

Comment: the best way to learn is to first do the unvestigation yourself - have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: I'm a novice programmer and have only used command line feedback to fix programs so far. I also have limited experience with dynamic memory allocation so I feel like I'm doing something simple wrong in regards to that but I can't seem to find what it is using basic commenting parts out to break down the problem type methods.

Comment: It was more like a suggestion than a question ;)

Comment: how would I go about doing that?

Comment: google for `c debug youroperatingsystem`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have put

```
_argcount=0;
_args[0]=NULL;
```

at the top of the rules section in hopes that these statements would be executed at the beginning of `yylex()`. And you've noticed that they aren't executed (it keeps appending to the previous values because `_argcount` never goes back to 0).

The obvious thing to do is move those statements into `getln()` just before the `yylex()`.

What you have now is a lexer that will ignore the string `_argcount=0;` in the input because it will match that pattern and there's no action to go with it. The second line is even cooler since the `[0]` is a character class. It makes the lexer ignore the string `_args0=NULL;`

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! I figured I might be able to fix it with a simple change to the lex code but I didn't really understand the syntax and I thought I was maybe supposed to use it exactly as it was given to me.

Comment: Also how would I add a simple function to return the argcount? still a bit confused about lex